# Python can't use values from constructor

Tags: python-3.x, methods, constructor, self

I have a problem with using values from my constructor. I'm passing three (input) values for my fuzzy logic which for some reason I can't use. I'm getting an error message: **name 'self' is not defined**.

I don't know what am I doing wrong since  I have a similar class in my code and that works fine? This is just a simple version of my code:

```
class FirstFuzzy:

    def __init__(self, length, arr, dep):
        self.veh_que = length
        self.veh_arr = arr
        self.veh_dep = dep

    print(self.veh_que)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please shift the print statement inside the constructor. Or create a method inside the class and then try to print that statement.

class FirstFuzzy:

```
def __init__(self, length, arr, dep):
    self.veh_que = length
    self.veh_arr = arr
    self.veh_dep = dep
    print(...)
```

Comment: So I can only use these values inside init or another method not outside?

Comment: Yes. You cannot reference something outside the scope.